# Does anyone have recommendations as to how or where I would go about getting 1-to-1 mentoring as a beginner programmer (preferably for free)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, math, data-structures

I picked up coding during quarantine and haven't gone a day without learning since. I've managed to learn the basics of Ruby in little under two weeks and run a few programs/started creating a basic app. Now I have to get a hang of Ruby on Rails. Furthermore, I have started learning Data Structures & Algorithms as a separate topic to complement the programming followed by Logic & Discrete Mathematics. I'm a very fast and curious learner and simply cannot just let a question be without knowing the solution to it (which led me to making my StackOverflow account).

Learning is always easier and more engaging when you have an enthusiastic and passionate person to guide you through a subject.

I was wondering if anyone knows where I can find a good one-to-one mentor that caters to an enthusiastic beginner programmer?

Alternatively, is there a recommended online forum, group or organisation that does the same thing?

Answers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately there isn't really a *great* place for this yet, perhaps because there's a point at which developers no longer wish to be mentored rather than rely upon a mutual network. StackOverflow being an obvious example.

[Coding Coach](https://codingcoach.io/) tries to tie mentors and mentees together, for free. In my experience it can be quite difficult to find active mentors on the platform though.
[CodeMentor](http://codementor.io/) isn't free but also has a large number of active mentors.
[RailsLink](https://www.rubyonrails.link/) has a channel called `beginners-and-mentors` for small bits of advice.

It can be quite difficult to find someone willing to engage one-to-one when you're learning because, unfortunately, it's often quite boring for the mentor. For that reason, networking with peers is a great way to learn when starting out. It also means that one 'mentor' can help a collective with greater ease.

Try reaching out to people on Twitter or other social media and try to be helpful where you can too. Even if you're only one week in you're a week ahead of someone who's not tried at all.